# Post method is not working in updateview django

Tags: python, django

I have a update view in django project. I need to override the post method because I am using multiple modelform. I have already override createview. And it is working fine.

views.py:

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Update a created a employee
    """

    login_url = '/authentication/login/'
    template_name = 'employee/employee_update_form.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddModelForm
    work_form_class = WorkExperienceForm
    education_form_class = EducationForm
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('employee:employee-list')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee_id = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee_id)
        education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee_id)


        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': self.form_class(instance=employee_id),
                                                    'work_form': self.work_form_class(instance=work_info),
                                                    'education_form': self.education_form_class(instance=education_info)
                                                    }
                                                )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        work_form = self.work_form_class(request.POST, prefix='work_form')
        education_form = self.education_form_class(request.POST, prefix='education_form')

        # Check form validation
        if form.is_valid() and work_form.is_valid() and education_form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            work = work_form.save(commit=False)
            education = education_form.save(commit=False)
            work.employee = instance
            education.employee = instance
            work.update()
            education.update()

            return redirect('employee:employee-list')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_form': work_form,
                                                    'education_form': education_form
                                                    }
                                                )
```

When I press update button of my form, error is giving showwing "This field already exist". It means when i update the form, it is posting data as a new form not as a update form.

I think my post method is not working. Where is the error in my post method?

Comment: I think it's better to write your own view instead of sub classing UpdateView if you are working with more than one model

Comment: can you give me an example???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own view like this instead of sub classing the generic view. Since you are working with more than one model here so it will be easy for you to write your own view.

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    .......

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee_id = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee_id)
        education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee_id)

        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=employee_id)
        work_form = self.work_form_class(request.POST, prefix='work_form', instance=work_info)
        education_form = self.education_form_class(request.POST, prefix='education_form',instance=education_info)

        # Check form validation
        if form.is_valid() and work_form.is_valid() and education_form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            work = work_form.save(commit=False)
            education = education_form.save(commit=False)
            work.employee = instance
            education.employee = instance
            work.save()
            education.save()

            return redirect('employee:employee-list')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_form': work_form,
                                                    'education_form': education_form
                                                    }
                                                )
```

Comment: It is working. But I need to fill the form twice. First when I edit a field and press the update button it returns the form again. That time I need to fill up again.This the update button works. So may be there is a bug in post method

Comment: @NextGenDigiTechV.O.F. please check if you have given correct prefix or not